# Vowpal Wabbit same results always

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit, multilabel-classification

I am using VW to try to predict multi classes. The strangest part is that it doesn't matter which parameters I use, the result is always the same.

Should that happen, maybe because of my data?

Details:

Around 90k lines of data. A line of the data:

```
1 2334225|SUBDEPT "D1SUB1" "D2SUB1" |DEPT "DEPT1" "DEPT2" |SCANCODE "11223442" "65434533543" |WDAY Friday |AMTBOUGHT 2
```

Its a multiclass problem,so the command line is:

```
vw --ect 38 ../Processed/train.vw.txt --loss_function logistic --link=logistic
```

The single parameter that changes something is from --ect to --oaa. I have tried adding the following, but none changes the final validation values:

- -c -k --passes 20 (goes until 8)
- --l1 or --l2
- --power_t
- --ignore D  or --ignore d (or s or su...)

the results are always

```
average loss = 0.911153 h
```

Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: Can you share your data?  Difficult to say otherwise. However, as a general rule, one shouldn't be forcing a loss (and/or link) function on top of reductions.  `--ect 38` is a multiclass (rather than binary-classification) problem.  So assuming the data has 38 different labels in the range `[1, 38]`, just let the `--ect` algorithm (as with other typical reductions) pick the preferred loss function (or leave the default alone).  HTH.

Comment: If I don't link anything, it gives me a loss of .34 (using the flag --loss_function logistic). If I do not use the flag, it gives me only the prediction, and I need the probabilities. Even though, removing the link and then changing parameters wont't change the loss as well.

Comment: Have you randomly shuffled the 90k lines of training data?

Comment: @arielf : "shouldn't be forcing a loss (and/or link) function on top of reductions" That's not true in general. The default loss is "squared", which is not suitable for getting probabilities with oaa.

Comment: @AdrianoAlmeida : If you want probabilities, use the newest VW version and `vw --oaa=38 --loss_function=logistic --probabilities` (with `--probabilities`, you don't need `--link` and VW will report both 0/1 loss and multi-class logistic loss). With `--ect` you cannot predict probabilities.

Comment: @MartinPopel they have the system order, but no class order. I will check on the --probabilities flag. Thanks

Comment: Few more unrelated comments on VW usage. * Feature names do not need double quoting (quote char has no special meaning, whitespace and colon is not allowed in feature names anyway). * Namespaces SUBDEPT and SCANCODE start with the same letter, so they cannot be distinguished with `--ignore`, `-q`, `--cubic` etc. * Namespaces are case sensitive (so `--ignore d` means smething different than `--ignore D`).

Comment: Tried --probabilities on VW 8.0. It says the option is unrecognised.  What version are u using?

Comment: Did you try to manually delete cache file before training when using `--passes` option?